# Is there any way to resize UIImageView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5

I'm trying to add image inside of UITableViewCell with UIImageView, and really added "normally", but when i change the size of UIImageView. I get this error message:

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one
> you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to
> figure out which you don't expect;        (2) find the code that added the
> unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a30b40 UIImageView:0x7fad5ed0fd90.height == 90   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a30b90 V:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7fad5ed10360]   (active, names:
> '|':Music.MusicsCell:0x7fad5ed0ec20'cellId' )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a30d70 UIStackView:0x7fad5ed10360.bottom ==
> Music.MusicsCell:0x7fad5ed0ec20'cellId'.bottom   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a31270 'UISV-canvas-connection' UIStackView:0x7fad5ed10360.top == UIImageView:0x7fad5ed0fd90.top
> (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a312c0 'UISV-canvas-connection' V:[UIImageView:0x7fad5ed0fd90]-(0)-|   (active, names:
> '|':UIStackView:0x7fad5ed10360 )>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a314f0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height'
> Music.MusicsCell:0x7fad5ed0ec20'cellId'.height == 90.5   (active)>" )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

but i've tried many things, like simple things, just image with background and size, example:

```
let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
imageView.size(size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
imageView.backgroundColor = .purple
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

and I don't know what I have to disappear this warning message.
Follow the code below:

MusicsVC (UITableViewController):

```
class MusicsVC: UITableViewController {
    let cellId = "cellId"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        
        tableView.register(MusicsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }
}

extension MusicsVC {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5;
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MusicsCell
    
        return cell;
    }
}
```

UITableViewCell:

```
class MusicsCell: UITableViewCell {

    let tituloLabel: UILabel = .textLabel(text: "Teste", fontSize: 16);
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.size(size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
        imageView.load(url: "https://studiosol-a.akamaihd.net/uploadfile/letras/fotos/d/7/4/2/d74238794c3024afbcba997e444fd2cb.jpg")
        
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
            imageView,
            tituloLabel
        ])
        
        stackView.spacing = 12
        
        addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.inset(view: stackView, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 12, bottom: 6, right: 12))
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of your code, and rather use the code formatting to copy and paste it into your questions. Photos of code make it incredibly hard for other people to efficiently assist.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add the code here in the stack overflow.

Comment: What is this line? `stackView.inset(view: stackView, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 12, bottom: 6, right: 12))`

Comment: its a function in extension of UIView which I created to add padding on cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose do you want this, but your code is a little bit confused to know what you really you want... Declare your table view, and add constraints :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let tableView = UITableView()
let cellId = "cellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(MusicsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
 }
}
```

now delegate and datasource

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 72 // 60 image view height + 6x2 padding from top and bottom = 72
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MusicsCell
    
    return cell;
 }
}
```

and this how your cell looks like:

```
class MusicsCell: UITableViewCell {

let tituloLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Testo"
    label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .regular)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

let myImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    iv.clipsToBounds = true
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    return iv
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://studiosol-a.akamaihd.net/uploadfile/letras/fotos/d/7/4/2/d74238794c3024afbcba997e444fd2cb.jpg") else {return}
    myImageView.downloadImage(from: url) // this is my extension to load image from url, you can use yours
    
    contentView.addSubview(myImageView)
    myImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
    myImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
    myImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    myImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    
    contentView.addSubview(tituloLabel)
    tituloLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tituloLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    tituloLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tituloLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError()
 }
}
```

and this is the result

[image]